# Upload multiple files to server with php not uploading to server all files

Tags: php, mysql, forms, file-upload, server

Hi at all i got a problem i got a form which uploads files and insert into mysql the mysql insert part is working  but he only moves one file of the three to the server need please some help here is my code. 
The Upload Form:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="add-exposes.php" method="POST">  Expose Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>  Expose Beschreibung: <textarea style="width: 810px; height: 200px" name="expose_desc" class="textarea"></textarea><br>  Expose Kategorie:<select name="expose_cat" size="3"> 
                        <?php 
                    mysql_connect("xxx.de.mysql", "xxxx", "xxx") or die(mysql_error()) ;  mysql_select_db("handwerker_verb") or die(mysql_error()) ;

                    $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cats") or die(mysql_error());
                    while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) {
                    echo '<option value="'.$info['id'].'">'.$info['cat'].'</option>';
                    } ?>


                         </select><!--<input type="text" name="expose_cat">--><br>Expose Preis:<input type="text" name="price"> <br> Bild: <input type="file" name="photo"><br> <input type="file" name="photo1"><br> <input type="file" name="photo2"><br>   <input type="submit" value="Add">  </form>
```

Add to server and mysql:

```
<?php   $target = "images/";  $target = $target . basename( $_FILES['photo']['name']);
$target1 = "images/";  $target1 = $target1 . basename( $_FILES['photo1']['name']);
$target2 = "images/";  $target2 = $target2 . basename( $_FILES['photo2']['name']);

        $name=$_POST['name'];  $expose_desc=$_POST['expose_desc'];  $expose_cat=$_POST['expose_cat'];  $pic=($_FILES['photo']['name']);  $price=$_POST['price']; $pic1=($_FILES['photo1']['name']); $pic2=($_FILES['photo2']['name']); 

        mysql_connect("xxxx.de.mysql", "xx", "xxx") or die(mysql_error()) ;  mysql_select_db("handwerker_verb") or die(mysql_error()) ;

          mysql_query("INSERT INTO `exposes` VALUES ('', '$name', '$pic', '$expose_desc', '$expose_cat', '$price', '$pic1', '$pic2' )") ; 

          if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], $target))  {   echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). " has been uploaded, and your information has been added to the directory";  } 
          elseif(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo1']['tmp_name'], $target1))  {   echo "The 2 file ". basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). " has been uploaded, and your information has been added to the directory";  } 
          elseif(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo2']['tmp_name'], $target2))  {   echo "The 3 file ". basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). " has been uploaded, and your information has been added to the directory";  }

           else {    echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file.";  }  ?>
```

Comment: Only one file will be uploaded because you have if-elseif-elseif, change that to if-if-if.

Comment: thanks will gie it atry give you feedback in minute

Comment: awsome thanks working now

Comment: I added my solution as answer, please mark it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

move_uploaded_file returns true on success, the remaining elseif are never reached.
Try something like this:

```
$error = false;

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], $target))  
{   
echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). " has been uploaded, and your information has been added to the directory";  
} else $error = true;

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo1']['tmp_name'], $target1))  
{   
echo "The 2 file ". basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). " has been uploaded, and your information has been added to the directory";  
} else $error = true; 

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo2']['tmp_name'], $target2))  
{   
echo "The 3 file ". basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). " has been uploaded, and your information has been added to the directory";  
} else $error = true;

if($error)
   echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file.";
```