# how to upload multiple files, store their paths in different columns in a mysql database row

Tags: php, mysql, file, upload, path

Hello i am trying to create a subscription form, that allows  a user to fill in a form and upload multiple files.
already i have gotten some directions on this site as regards uploading a file and storing their paths in a database using this.

```
     <form method="post" action="addMember.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <p>
              Please Enter the Band Members Name.
            </p>
            <p>
              Band Member or Affiliates Name:
            </p>
            <input type="text" name="nameMember"/>
            <p>
              Please Enter the Band Members Position. Example:Drums.
            </p>
            <p>
              Band Position:
            </p>
            <input type="text" name="bandMember"/>
            <p>
              Please Upload a Photo of the Member in gif or jpeg format. The file name should be named after the Members name. If the same file name is uploaded twice it will be overwritten! Maxium size of File is 35kb.
            </p>
            <p>
              Photo:
            </p>
            <input type="hidden" name="size" value="350000">
            <input type="file" name="photo"> 
            <p>
              Please Enter any other information about the band member here.
            </p>
            <p>
              Other Member Information:
            </p>
<textarea rows="10" cols="35" name="aboutMember">
</textarea>
            <p>
              Please Enter any other Bands the Member has been in.
            </p>
            <p>
              Other Bands:
            </p>
            <input type="text" name="otherBands" size=30 />
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <input TYPE="submit" name="upload" title="Add data to the Database" value="Add Member"/>
          </form>
and the php code for inserting this

   <?php

//This is the directory where images will be saved
$target = "your directory";
$target = $target . basename( $_FILES['photo']['name']);

//This gets all the other information from the form
$name=$_POST['nameMember'];
$bandMember=$_POST['bandMember'];
$pic=($_FILES['photo']['name']);
$about=$_POST['aboutMember'];
$bands=$_POST['otherBands'];


// Connects to your Database
mysql_connect("yourhost", "username", "password") or die(mysql_error()) ;
mysql_select_db("dbName") or die(mysql_error()) ;

//Writes the information to the database
mysql_query("INSERT INTO tableName (nameMember,bandMember,photo,aboutMember,otherBands)
VALUES ('$name', '$bandMember', '$pic', '$about', '$bands')") ;

//Writes the photo to the server
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], $target))
{

//Tells you if its all ok
echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). " has been uploaded, and your information has been added to the directory";
}
else {

//Gives and error if its not
echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file.";
}
?>
```

this stores the path of the uploaded file in the column "photo" below

```
id nameMember bandMember photo aboutMember otherBands
```

but what i want do is have mutiple upload fields and store their paths in different columns photo, photo1 , photo2
e.g

```
 <input type="file" name="photo"> 
 <input type="file" name="photo1"> 
 <input type="file" name="photo2"> 
id nameMember bandMember photo photo1 photo2 aboutMember otherBands
```

please how do i go about this

Comment: all input should be <input type="file" name="photo[]"> keep id's different. After post Check $_FILES

Comment: thanks am sorry but that brief explaination wont help, i want to store the different paths in different columns on the same row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to change their as

```
$pic1=($_FILES['photo1']['name']);
$pic2=($_FILES['photo2']['name']);
$pic3=($_FILES['photo3']['name']);
for($i=1;$i<=3;$i++)
{
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo'.$i]['tmp_name'], $target))
{

//Tells you if its all ok
echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). " has been uploaded, and your information has been added to the directory";
}
else {

//Gives and error if its not
echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file.";
}
}
and in your query you can change it with like a

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO tableName 
               (nameMember,bandMember,photo,photo1,photo2,aboutMember,otherBands)
               VALUES ('$name', '$bandMember', '$pic','$pic1','$pic2', '$about', '$bands')") ;
```

i hope this may help another way is you can take input name as array and  use loop for getting path , i recommend you to chnage the name of input type file like photo1,photo2,.....photon

Comment: you havent talked about writing it into the server section

Comment: means what you want to say

Comment: how do i handle the multiple file upload there

Comment: great nice one. i also got a solution on this link,   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26546940/upload-multiple-files-to-server-with-php-not-uploading-to-server-all-files